# AWS Copilot and AWS VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, vpn

I am using the AWS Copilot system to deploy microservices. I have encountered an issue where I need a static IP for the services deployed in ECS due to a Site-to-Site VPN. I am interested in how I can configure Copilot to assign a static IP to a service deployed in ECS, as this is necessary for firewalls. This IP must also be part of the CIDRs defined by the VPN Site-to-Site.

Best regards, Mihael

I just need answer if this is possible or not,.. Or I must deploy my service to EC2 in AWS

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a static IP to ECS Fargate tasks. If you were deploying your ECS tasks to EC2 instances instead of Fargate, and configured them to use `host` networking mode, you could assign a static IP to the EC2 instances. However I'm not sure if CoPilot supports the EC2 deployment mode for ECS tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can assign a static IP to your Copilot service. Update the manifest.yml of your Load Balanced Web Service to include

```
network:
  vpc:
    placement: private
```

Deploy and you'll find a NAT Gateway added to your VPC. Look at your VPC to see the exposed static public IP address. I updated an existing service which kept running as normal but with a new static egress IP.